# iPad 3 set auto-width on webpage

Tags: ipad, width, scale, viewport

I am creating a website. The width of my page is too wide, that means I have to scroll to the side. On the page there is no element with fixed width, so why do I still have to scroll sidewards? I thought the following meta tag would handle this issue.

Markup:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Can you just add a fiddle or any test link? I think your viewport meta tag is allright. All you need to do is to twice check your code with firebug or webkit inspector where is this width is coming from? There should be any child element that is exceeding the width of its parent width including padding+border+margin etc. Hope you'll figure out.